# SQL Server 2005 FOR XML

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, sqlxml

I want to export data from a table to a specifically formatted XML file. I am fairly new to XML files, so what I am after may be quite obvious but I just cant find what I am looking for on the net.

The format of the XML results I need are:

```
    <data>
        <event 
            start="May 28 2006 09:00:00 GMT"
            end="Jun 15 2006 09:00:00 GMT"
            isDuration="true"
            title="Writing Timeline documentation"
            image="http://simile.mit.edu/images/csail-logo.gif">
            A few days to write some documentation
        </event>
     </data>
```

My table structure is:

```
name VARCHAR(50),
description VARCHAR(255),
startDate DATETIME,
endDate DATETIME
```

(I am not too interested in the XML fields image or isDuration at this point in time).

I have tried:

```
SELECT [name]
           ,[description]
           ,[startDate]
           ,[endTime]

  FROM [testing].[dbo].[time_timeline]
  FOR XML RAW('event'), ROOT('data'), type
```

Which gives me:

```
<data>
    <event name="Test1" 
           description="Test 1 Description...." 
           startDate="1900-01-01T00:00:00" 
           endTime="1900-01-01T00:00:00" 
    />
    <event name="Test2" 
           description="Test 2 Description...." 
           startDate="1900-01-01T00:00:00" 
           endTime="1900-01-01T00:00:00" 
    />
</data>
```

What I am missing, is the description needs to be outside of the event attributes, and there needs to be a  tag.

Is anyone able to point me in the correct direction, or point me to a tutorial or similar on how to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT
    name "event/@name"
    , startDate "event/@start"
    , description "event"
FROM
    [testing].[dbo].[time_timeline]
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('data')
```

Things to note:

- In order to get `description` as the text content of `event`, we have to 'step up' a level and use `PATH('')`, and specify the name `event` in the alias for all columns
- All attribute-centric columns must come before all non-attribute-centric columns

For learning this stuff (or at least getting an idea of how to do what you want), see [the docs for `FOR XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137%28SQL.90%29.aspx) and just play around with your own tables and desired XML structures.

Comment: This is excellent, I remember coming across something similar to this but couldnt get it to work so just assumed it wasnt what I was after.  The way that you have explained it will help me with other queries that I have to do.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Consider switching to FOR XML PATH (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx for documentation)

A very partial example:

```
SELECT
    [name] 
   ,[description] 
   ,[startDate]   "@start"
   ,[endTime]     "@end"
  FROM [testing].[dbo].[time_timeline] 
  FOR XML PATH('event'), ROOT('data')
```

Comment: This will put `description` in its own node, named `description`; also attribute-centric columns must come first.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to demonstrate the approach in a general manner rather than provide a specific working example